# Why are there 2 different fingerprints for ssh depending on what network I connect from?

Tags: ssh, sshd, openssh

When I connect to my computer over ssh on the local network, putty fives me the correct fingerprint of

```
ssh-rsa 2048 ad:e3:4c:e3:d0:6f:81:2e:05:94:77:6c:0f:2c:a8:7f
```

This matches the fingerprint on my computer when I run `ssh-keygen -E md5 -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`

When I connect over the internet putty gives me a fingerprint of

```
ssh-rsa 1040 86:03:d0:87:3d:67:3a:9a:9b:83:7a:39:a7:2e:e7:e0
```

Why is it giving me a different fingerprint, what is this ssh-rsa 1040?

Comment: It is fingerprint of different key. You are either connecting to different server, your server offers more keys or there is man in the middle attack going on.

Comment: It is definitely my server.  I'm running lubuntu 16.04 I'm pretty sure all the keys that sshd uses are in /etc/ssh/ `ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
ssh_host_ecdsa_key
ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
ssh_host_ed25519_key
ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
ssh_host_rsa_key
ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`  I don't know how it could be a man in the middle, I access it using local network ip, 192.168.1.100  and it gives correct key, and when I use my internet ip, it just goes to the router and back to my server, and gets a different key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot confirm that key fingerprint as coming from your ubuntu host, the likely cause is that you are not really connecting to the host/service that you think you are.

Not only are you getting a different host key, the key length of 1040 seems a bit peculiar. Doing a quick google search on the fingerprint 86:03:d0:87:3d:67:3a:9a:9b:83:7a:39:a7:2e:e7:e0 finds a hit in a gist of "Top 1,000 Duplicate SSH Fingerprints on the Internet", while not conclusive, at least makes it even more suspect. Plausibly, it may be that your router has a SSH service, and your connection is your router instead of the server behind it.

Since your ubuntu host is local, you can check the logs on the server to see if the ssh connection is being made (and check that the source IP is what you expect). Also check the client side netstat listing of established connections to validate that the destination IP matches what you expect.

If you cannot find a legitimate reason for that key fingerprint to be originating from your server, assume that it is not your server. If you attempted to login with a password, successfully or unsuccessfully, to a server with that fingerprint, assume that your username/password has been compromised by some unknown party.

Comment: Suggest: check server logs _and_ netstat to see if connection actually arrived (as well as client netstat to see where you think it went).

Answer (score 0):

The modem I have is a SmartRG SR505N
I did do a bunch of netstat and looking around, and eventually did find that even though the router says it moved it's own ssh port 22 to 2222 after I enabled port forwarding to my lan side server, it doesn't actually move it's own ssh server, but it's weird, sometimes it would work, other times it wouldn't. I read about this problem on http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r29001235-DSL-Port-forwarding-on-SmartRG-SR505 that's the modem I have.  Guess I have to use a different port then, oh well.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't noticed it first. In my environment there are 2 servers. I can only forward the ssh port to one, let's say serverA.

I have my router configured to give me the local ip for each domain which serverA and serverB have.

Locally all is fine. But via ssh there is only serverA reachable. Since all the domains point to the same ip when I wanted to connect to serverB I in reality connected to serverA. Forgot about the proxy setup in my ssh config.